# Pass string from xcode project to imported sub-project

Tags: ios, nsstring, appdelegate

I'm trying to send a variable from the classic AppDelegate file to method which is in another project.

So I have:

```
- My Project
     -> AppDelegate.m
     -> AppDelegate.h
     -> ViewController.m
     -> ViewController.h
     -  CordovaLib.xproj
             -> Private (folder)
                   -> Plugins (folder)
                          -> CDVUIWebViewEngine (folder)
                                   -> CDVUIWebViewNavigationDelegate.m
```

When the app launches, I'm getting a variable (actually the filepath of a pdf file I open from another app and which got imported to my app).

I'd like to send this string to `CDVUIWebViewNavigationDelegate.m` so that I can use it there.

Any type of help would be appreciated, couldn't find anything helpful about that !
PS: I'm everything but an objective-c expert !

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode (which is an IDE, not a language and not something that influences how your code executes.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive comment.

Comment: Maybe you should calm down. This wasn't ironic, I actually thought this had something to do with Xcode and its architecture.

Comment: I apologize. Your first comment seems a bit more sarcastic than sincere and I overreacted at that.